# Routes in Symfony2

Tags: resources, symfony, routes, requirements

In some symfony2 project I have next definition of routes:

```
MyBundle_Default:
    resource: "routing/default.yml"
    prefix: /{slug}-{resource_id}
    requirements:
        slug: "[a-z\-]+"
        resource_id: "\d+"
```

But this requirements don't work. 
For example, if I have "-" in slug (e.g. "test-route") url like `/test-route-9` do not work.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was indeed a bug. At least in Symfony 3.4.36, all works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, I think your problem comes from the dash character. Let me explain. Say the url entered is `/test-route-9`. With your requirements, the slug matched would be `test-route-` because your regex states that is characters between `a-z` or the dash `-` that can be matched.

Regex will match every thing it can, so it will "eat" the dash character. By "eating" it, the rest would be only `9` which would not be correct because the routing expects another dash before matching the `resource_id` portion. Hence, this url wouldn't match as you expect.

Simple fix is to separate components with a `/` instead of dash, or change the character separating your slug to differentiate it from the url component separator.

Fix by changing separator in url:

```
prefix: /{slug}/{resource_id}
requirements:
    slug: "[a-z\-]+"
    resource_id: "\d+"
```

Or:

```
prefix: /{slug}_{resource_id}
requirements:
    slug: "[a-z\-]+"
    resource_id: "\d+"
```

Fix by changing separator for the slug directly:

```
prefix: /{slug}-{resource_id}
requirements:
    slug: "[a-z_]+"
    resource_id: "\d+"
```

I'm pretty sure the problem comes from this. Did not test anything, but worth a try just to be sure the problem lies with the dash character separator.

Comment: thanks, but in previous answer I commented about working constructions. And again, I need to use pattern {slug}-{resource_id} (without slashes and underscores).

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, you put the requirement on hotel_id but define in the url resource_id!

Comment: Can you also provide the content of default.yml?

Comment: It doesn't matter. There are regular routes without params. And if I put them into main route file (without importing resource with route) - I get working constructions but with a lot of "copy-pasting" which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
slug: "[a-z\-]+(?<!-)"
```

This will make sure that the regex does NOT match the last dash, which is the problem as mentioned in Matts answer.

I hope it works for you :)